# CSS - Align the input to another input

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a input month, day, and year and i want to align the day and year to month. i want to center all of my form so i put a `margin-left:500px;` to every element of the form. Can someone help me about this?

Here is the picture of what i want to do
[image]

**update**

```
here is my whole code. 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <style>
                .date{
                    margin-left: 500px;
                    width: 160px;
                }

            .title{
                margin-left: 500px;
                width: 300px;
            }
            .etitle{
                margin-left: 500px;
                width: 200px;
            }
            .evenue{
                margin-left:500px;
                width: 150px;
            }
            form-group, label{
                margin-left: 500px;
            }
            form-group, input{
                margin-left: 500px;
            }
            img{
                margin-left: 500px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;

            }
            .content{
                margin-left: 500px;
                width: 400px;
            }
            .btn-info{
                margin-left: 500px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            .month,.day,.year,.stime,.etime{
                width: 120px;
                margin-left: 500px;

            }

        </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</h1>

    <form method="post" action ="admin.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">



                <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="title">News Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control title" id="title" placeholder="News Title" >
                </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="title">Date</label>
               <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control date" id="date" placeholder="Date" >  
            </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="content">News Content</label>
                 <textarea class="form-control content" name="content" rows="5" id="content" ></textarea>
          </div>    


                  <img id="blah" src="" alt="image here" width="200px" height="140px"/>
                   <input id="image" name="image" class="fileupload" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
                 <button type="submit" name="submit" class='btn btn-info '>Post news</button>



        <hr>

              <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="title">Event Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="etitle" class="form-control etitle" id="etitle" placeholder="Event Title" >
            </div>  


              <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="title">Event Venue</label>
                    <input type="text" name="evenue" name="evenue" class="form-control evenue" id="evenue" placeholder="Event Venue">
            </div>  



        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="month">Start Date:</label>
        <select class="form-control month" id="month" name="month">

                  </select>
                </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="form-control day" name="day">
                       <option value="Day">Day</option>

                  </select>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control year" name="year">

              </select>
            </div>


      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="month">End Date:</label>
          <select class="form-control month" id="month" name="emonth">

                  </select>
                </div>  


                <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="form-control day" name="eday">
                       <option value="Day">Day</option>

                  </select>
                </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control year" name="eyear">

              </select>
            </div>


        div class="form-group">
       <label for="stime">Start Time:</label>
          <select class="form-control stime" id="stime" name="stime">

              </select>
            </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="etime">End Time:</label>
        <select class="form-control etime" id="etime" name="etime">

              </select>
            </div>

              <button type="submit" name="submitevent" class='btn btn-info '>Post news</button>


</form>
```

Comment: Please edit to include the whole form, but please remove all those options... it's enough to keep one month, one day etc. in order to keep this readable.

Comment: @Eiko hi sir. i already edited.

Answer (score 0):

Add float property:

```
 .month,.day,.year{
         width: 120px;
         float: left;
         margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

Or you can add a bootstrap CSS class:

```
 .month,.day,.year{
         width: 120px;
         margin-right: 5px;
 }

<select class="form-control month pull-left"
```

To the select elements.

Comment: It's not properly align :(

Answer (score 0):

If your whant compatibility with IE10 or older you can use float:left, [css floating 2 inputfields in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138787/css-floating-2-inputfields-in-a-form)

But if don't, I will use display:flex, [CSS display: flex, align-center and button with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741025/css-display-flex-align-center-and-button-with-checkboxes) (not the same, but I thinks this can help)